# Unable to bind drop down list in telerik kendo mvc grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid

I'm having difficulty binding a dropdown list in a telerik mvc kendo grid.

I have a collection of records that are bound to the grid and each record has a Foregin Key property. Currently it is rendering a text box in the place where the dropdown should be.

[image: Detail slot rendering as text input field]

I have searched throrugh the Telerik documentation and also the demo code where they have a working dropdown however it only shows them using a `ClientTemplate` on that field and doesn't show the code for that template.

In my controller action I populate the ViewData with my collection as follows:

```
 IEnumerable<DetailSlotDTO> slots = Mapper.ToDTO(detailSlotRepository.GetAll());
 ViewData["Slots"] = slots;
```

And the DetailSlotDTO class is as follows:

```
 public class DetailSlotDTO
 { 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
 }
```

I am then trying to setup the grid in my view as follows:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<SFT.Web.DTOs.SyndicatedRecordDTO>()
.Name("slotGrid")
.Columns(c =>
{
    c.Bound(f => f.DetailSlot).ClientTemplate(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
        .BindTo(ViewData["Slots"] as IEnumerable<SFT.Web.DTOs.DetailSlotDTO>)
        .Name("SlotDesc_#=Id#")
        .DataTextField("Description")
        .DataValueField("Id")
        .ToClientTemplate().ToHtmlString()
        );
    c.Bound(f => f.Client);
    c.Bound(f => f.Product);
    c.Bound(f => f.Start);
    c.Bound(f => f.End);
    c.Bound(f => f.PurchaseOrder);
    c.Bound(f => f.Value);
    c.Bound(f => f.KPIPenalty);
    c.Bound(f => f.Notes);
})
.ToolBar(t =>
{
    t.Create();

})
.Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
.DataSource(d => d
    .Ajax()
    .Batch(false)
    .ServerOperation(false)
    .Model(m =>
    {
        m.Id(r => r.Id);
        m.Field(r => r.DetailSlot);
        m.Field(r => r.Client).Editable(true);
        m.Field(r => r.Product).Editable(true);
        m.Field(r => r.Start).Editable(true);
        m.Field(r => r.End).Editable(true);
        m.Field(r => r.PurchaseOrder).Editable(true);
        m.Field(r => r.Value).Editable(true);
        m.Field(r => r.KPIPenalty).Editable(true);
        m.Field(r => r.Notes).Editable(true);
    })
    .Read(read => read.Action("SlotGrid_Read", "SalesFee", new { id = @Model.SalesFeeId }))
    .Create(create => create.Action("SlotGrid_Create", "SalesFee"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("SlotGrid_Update", "SalesFee"))
    .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("SlotGrid_Destroy", "SalesFee"))
)
)
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I spent all day yesterday playing around trying to get it to work and haven't had much luck.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show dropdown in edit mode than you have to use "ForeignKey" column in kendo Grid.

```
columns.ForeignKey(p => p.DetailSlot, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Slots"], "Id", "Description");
```

Please check [**link**](http://jayeshgoyani.blogspot.in/2013/01/set-column-editable-mode-based-on_16.html), in this link I have posted full code and demo project.